# Initializing inflate state

Tags: android

Initializing inflate state am getting continously this in logcat any one help to figure from where am getting this and how to prevent this?

Comment: kindly provide more details...  screen shot or logs.. your code..etc

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout table = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_channels);
for (int i = 0; i < columnsNumber; i++) {
    LinearLayout column = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.channels_list_column, table,false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `ListView` recycle views and give them to you to reconsider use them again
So you must check `convertedView` paramter in `Adapter.getView` before inflate a new view